# What is Request Payload, why it captures data which I send.?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express

Am developing single page application using Angular as front-end tier and node for backend, while user logs submit it capture user name and password in Request Payload.
Am not aware about this, why it captures and how to restrict this.
Below is sample for payload data.

[image: Valid XHTML].

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginform" (ngSubmit)="login()">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">User name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name" placeholder="User Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="password">
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" formControlName="validate"/>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginform.valid" class="btn">
login</button>
</form>
```

login-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../guards/auth.guard';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from '../../data-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.html',
  styleUrls: [ './login-page.css' ]
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  loginform: FormGroup;
  previousUrl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: DataService, private authGuard: AuthGuard,
  private router: Router){
    this.loginform = this.fb.group({
     'name': [null, Validators.required],
     'password': ['', Validators.required],
     'validate' : ''
      });
  }

 ngOnInit()  { }
 login(){
    const user = {
      "email" : this.loginform.get('name').value,
      "password" : this.loginform.get('password').value
    }
   this.service.login(user)
   .subscribe((data) => {
     if (!data.success) {
       this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger';
     }
     else {
       this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success';
       this.service.storeUserData(data.token, data.user, data.admin);
       setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Success');
          if (this.previousUrl) {
            this.router.navigate([this.previousUrl]);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          }
        }, 1000)
     }
   })
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
login(user){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', user).map(
      res=> res
    )
}
```

Rest API:

```
exports.user_login = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user[0].email,
              userId: user[0]._id
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token,
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: What you will send from frontend that will we always available to `request payload` .

Answer (score 3):

The payload is the *body* of your post request. The body is the second parameter (`user`) you are sending in with:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', user)
```

The user object was populated by yourself in the component:

```
const user = {
  "email" : this.loginform.get('name').value,
  "password" : this.loginform.get('password').value
}
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Comment: @Prashanth - What do you mean? You can _restrict_ what you send, by only sending the data you want to send. If you, for example don't want to send the _password_, then you don't include it in the _body_ (which, in your case, is the _user_ object that you include in as the second parameter in the _post_ call)